# Varnish isn't caching any page

Tags: caching

I have a Docksal stack that includes Varnish (with the `acquia` Docksal stack).

I made a static HTML page in the docroot, and Varnish is caching it, as shown by the HTTP headers:

```
$ curl -IL http://varnish.cx.docksal/cached.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 09:01:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 10:39:03 GMT
ETag: "0-5a85962945fc0"
X-Varnish: 5 3
Age: 2
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
Cache-Control: private,no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I've set up a new Drupal 8 site, created one node, and the HTTP headers show it's not getting cached by Varnish.

With https://www.drupal.org/project/adv_varnish enabled, I get this:

```
$ curl -IL http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 09:02:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.11
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: MISS
Link: <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="canonical", <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="shortlink", <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="revision"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
Vary: X-Bin
X-Grace: 10
X-TTL: 0
X-Tag: 32f5 de19 143b 864e 4f2e e312 1baa 1f8b 88c8 e062 678c 7c65 0b6e 93b3 7d01 76fd 7c7e 09a2 476d 4999 e459 f70b 4016 fd28 67aa 5ff8 a8bc bdb1
X-Adv-Varnish: Cache-enabled
X-Varnish-Secret: 648858c54f78622c9df4c549f87d71cda274420faedc3c5de92a856cb939a914
X-Deflate-Key: b91f02cf5af93c1c9141ba365d5852c9d12df6fd39f8b5d9c3b80dc1bc1428e1
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 15:38:17 GMT
ETag: "1592494697"
X-Varnish: 32772
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
Cache-Control: private,no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Without that module enabled, I get this:

```
$ curl -IL http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 09:15:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.11
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: MISS
Link: <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="canonical", <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="shortlink", <http://varnish.cx.docksal/node/1>; rel="revision"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
X-Varnish: 98338
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
Cache-Control: private,no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

In both cases, Varnish isn't caching the page (I'm loading it twice, and I'd expect to have a Varnish cache hit the second time).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Varnish won't cache by default if you have cookies. You also may need to set some more response cache headers like cache-enabled `cache-control` and future `expires` to enable varnish caching.

Comment: I thought that as an anonymous user, there aren't any cookies?